# Por que DirectoryInfo.Exists é verdadeiro após excluir o diretório?

Tags: c#

No seguinte código

```
var Directory_02 = "TEST_01";

DirectoryInfo directory2 = new DirectoryInfo(Directory_02);
directory2.Create();

if (directory2.Exists)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} exists: {1}", Directory_02, directory2.Exists);
    directory2.Delete();
    System.Console.WriteLine("{0} exists: {1}", Directory_02, directory2.Exists);
}
```

Temos a saída

```
TEST_01 exists: True
TEST_01 exists: True
```

Por que quando `directory2.Delete()` é chamado `directory2.Exists` continua `true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pesquisando mais um pouco, vi que o correto seria usar

```
directory2.Refresh();
```

depois do

```
directory2.Delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa reinstanciar a variável `directory2` ou chamar o método `Refresh()` após excluí-lo (ou criá-lo).

```
directory2 = new DirectoryInfo(Directory_02); // reinstanciando
directory2.Refresh(); // ou atualizando...
```

Se olhar no [código-fonte de `DirectoryInfo.Exists`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/directoryinfo.cs):

```
// Tests if the given path refers to an existing DirectoryInfo on disk.
// 
// Your application must have Read permission to the directory's
// contents.
//
public override bool Exists {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    get
    {
        try
        {
            if (_dataInitialised == -1)
                Refresh();
            if (_dataInitialised != 0) // Refresh was unable to initialise the data
                return false;

            return _data.fileAttributes != -1 && (_data.fileAttributes & Win32Native.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Se alguma vez você checou se o diretório existe (alterando o valor de `_dataInitialised`), ele sempre retornará aquele valor, independente de mudança a não ser que chame `Refresh()` ou construa outro objeto.